# Why isn't Centreon graphing all the series?

Tags: nagios, centreon

I am using Centreon with Nagios, and one of our plugins returns the following performance data:

```
0000 : memory OK | memory-slab-cache=32636928(octets); memory-swap-cache=827392(octets); memory-page-tables=4063232(octets); memory-vmalloc_used=3600384(octets); memory-apps=558448640(octets); memory-buffer=65933312(octets); memory-swap=6434816(octets); memory-cache=3211509
```

However, only the memory-slab-cache series is being graphed, the others don't show up.

Things I have tried:

- Removing 'memory-' from the string and changing 'octets' to 'k' in order to reduce the size
- Changing the scale (dividing everything by 1024) to avoid the numbers being 'too big'

Neither has worked. In the first test, it has just graphed 'slab-cache' instead of 'memory-slab-cache', and in the second it has just graphed the 'new' values of 'memory-slab-cache' correctly.

Is there something glaringly obvious that I've missed?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking on the Centreon forums, it turns out that the unit mustn't be in brackets, so instead of:

```
0000 : memory OK | memory-slab-cache=32636928(octets); memory-swap-cache=827392(octets); memory-page-tables=4063232(octets); memory-vmalloc_used=3600384(octets); memory-apps=558448640(octets); memory-buffer=65933312(octets); memory-swap=6434816(octets); memory-cache=3211509
```

if should read:

```
0000 : memory OK | memory-slab-cache=32636928octets; memory-swap-cache=827392octets; memory-page-tables=4063232octets; memory-vmalloc_used=3600384octets; memory-apps=558448640octets; memory-buffer=65933312octets; memory-swap=6434816octets; memory-cache=3211509
```